# Как удалить блок при заходе пользователя в личный кабинет

Tags: wordpress, функции, условия

Здравствуйте у меня Wordpress так вот мне надо чтобы какой-то блок был виден до тех пор пока пользователь не авторизуется на сайте, как он авторизуется так сразу определенный блок должен удалятся. Знаю что есть проверка на условие авторизирован ли пльзователь

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Вы авторизованы на сайте!';
}
else {
    echo 'Вы всего лишь пользователь!';
}
```

Но к сожалению не знаю где этот код должен быть пробовал добавлять в function.php и ошибки появились, заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ура!! Я уже сам разобрался, вопрос решен тема закрыта!))